# Apache log file format analysis by R

Tags: r

I was trying to do the analysis of weblog files by R. I am comfortable to deal with the date and bytes, wherever numeric data is present but fail to deal with the strings.

From the log file (log file in CSV format), I want to find out the particular user (with help of IP and Agents) and its total spending on the web page.

Comment: It's look like you want someone to do the job for you. What did you try so far ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logfile analysis in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664997/logfile-analysis-in-r)

Comment: @dickoa : Whatever the work I have done, I was trying to put the snap of it over here but recent member are not eligible to put the snap that i got when I was trying to share it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numurous libraries to do this kind of analysis, although I could find none in R. A google for `parse apache logfile` yielded [a library in Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~akira/Apache-ParseLog-1.02/ParseLog.pm), and `python parse apache logfile` yields the [Scratchy library](http://scratchy.sourceforge.net/). Both rely on [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to parse the contents of the file.

From here there are two ways to deal with the apache logfile:

- Call perl or python from R, either using a direct link, or using a system call (this is simpler).
- Take the idea from the perl or python lib and use it to implement R versions of the functions. This will take a lot of time.

You refer to a csv file, but I think the libraries above work with the original text file with the Apache log, so I'd use those, and not your csv file.

In addition, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664997/logfile-analysis-in-r) mentions an answer by @doug ([profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66549/doug)) where he states that he has created some functions to create visualizations of apache logfile data, parsed by Python. Maybe you could send him a message or mail and see if he is willing to share the code.

Answer (score 0):

Logfile analysis in R is an interesting topic we had before, you can find our discussion right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664997/logfile-analysis-in-r). Maybe this discussion might also help you to adjust to the SO etiquette in order to get better feedback (not to take anything away from yours, Paul).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, the link was already in my answer btw.